# Using <%= %> inside server side controls gives The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

I am using to use `<%= %>` inside server controls and gives me error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

This is my code:

```
 <asp:Menu runat="server" >
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Candidates" NavigateUrl="<%=Constants.AccountPageUrl %>" />
        </Items>
 </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Is the control being loaded into a Master page?

Comment: Or try it without enclosing it in double quotes! `NavigateUrl=<%= varName %>`

Answer (score 0):

try the following.. It may help you

```
NavigateUrl="<%#Constants.AccountPageUrl %>"
```

Comment: That will never work. Since # is only used when we data bind it. In this case I have static menu items placed.

Comment: go through this link...it may help you http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/aspnet-controls-collection-cannot-be.html

Comment: @Jack - the pound sign hack is a work-around - but only 1/2 the picture.  Page.DataBind() also needs to be added to the Master page.